# Disable delete option in Notes and attachment

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, custom-object

Requirement - I need to remove or disable a delete button from Notes and attachment  on VF page.

[image]

Even I tried to write a trigger but it is working on request which got generated not on the attachment. Please find the trigger details below :

```
trigger Demo on Object_name (before delete)

{   
     for(object_name a:trigger.old ) 
     {
       a.adderror('You do not have access to delete the attachment');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger is on the wrong object. If you want to react to delete events on classic Notes and Attachments, you'd need two triggers on the relevant sObjects:

- `Attachment` for classic Attachments
- `Note` for classic Notes

If you're working with Lightning's Files and Enhanced Notes, you'd be looking at the rather more complex suite of `ContentVersion`, `ContentDocument`, and `ContentDocumentLink`, but likewise you'd *not* be writing a trigger on the sObject to which the item is attached.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about classic attachment and classic notes.

Comment: @Anish What specifically are you asking about?

Comment: Can you please explain more about 2 triggers which you have mentioned in comments.

Comment: I'm not trying to be dense, Anish, but explain what? As stated above, your trigger is running on the wrong object, and you need to write two triggers on different objects to achieve this objective. The actual functionality of your trigger appears to be correct, it's just on the wrong object.